# react-hook-form how to check if form field is valid before form validation is fired

Tags: react-hook-form

I have the following

```js
const formFieldsSchema = z.object({
  fieldA: z.string().min(1, "field required"),
  fieldB: z.string().min(1, "field required"),
})

type FormFieldSchemaType = z.infer<typeof formFieldsSchema>

const MyForm = () => {

  const {register, formState} = useForm<FormFieldSchemaType>({
    mode: "onTouched",
    resolver: zodResolver(formFieldSchema)
  })

  // run some other process when the user clicks the button and field A is valid
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // check that field a is valid before doing whatever
    const fieldAIsValid = formState.errors.fieldA // if the button is clicked before the end-user has touched fieldA, there will be no errors even if fieldA is technically invalid.

    if(fieldAIsValid) {
      // run other process
    }
  }

  return <>
    <input {...register("fieldA")}/>
    <p>{formState.errors.fieldA?.message}</p>
    <input {...register("fieldB")}/>

    <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Do something</button>
  </>
}
```

Is there a way to check if an individual field is valid with the RHF api before the validation has been triggered via `trigger` or `mode: "onTouched"`.

As you can see, if the user clicks the button before they have touched fieldA, then the code sees no errors with fieldA and runs the thing. People have suggested using trigger or changing the mode from "onTouched", but then the validation errors will show on the UI and I don't want that before the user has touched the field.

In other words, what should I put here to get an accurate value of whether fieldA is valid or not?

```js
const fieldAIsValid = ??
```

Update: I also tried using `!formState.getFieldState("fieldA").invalid`, but that returned true (meaning valid) when fieldA hadn't even been touched.

Answer (score 0):

While using `react-hook-form` the `formState` holds the current state of the form, i.e. it gets updated in *real-time*.

**Addressing your question:**

> What should I put here to get an accurate value of whether fieldA is valid or not?

To check whether a particular field has correct value or not, you can directly access `formState.errors['fieldName']`.

If the value is correct, `formState.errors['fieldName']` will be `undefined`.
Else, it will contain the error object *(message, type and ref)*.

**Allowing all-time validation**:
To achieve this, you can use `useForm({mode: 'all'})`.

**Note**: *All-time validation might cause some performance impact.*

Comment: I have the formstate.errors already in the problem statement and mentioned that changing the mode causes another problem I don't want. Therefore this is not a valid solution for my use case, but thanks for your advice!